# How does this Imperial Assault character 'Shoot First'?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

We played the final mission in our Imperial Assault campaign.

In this mission, you have to

> Kill Vader(!)

The Imperial Player applied the 'shoot first' card to activate the character at the start of the round. They also reasoned that the character receives 2 actions.

However, the scenario special rules for the character are that he does not activate normally, but takes an action after each rebel player.

My questions are:

1. Can the 'shoot first' card be applied to this character in the final mission?
2. How many actions does the character get if he does 'shoot first'?

Answer (score 2):

#### The `Shoot First` card can be applied to any Imperial group, including villains, and that group will get a single activation through the use of the card, which translates to two actions.

Explanation:

`Shoot First` reads:

> Keep this card secret. Play it during any mission at the start of a round. An Imperial group may interrupt to perform **an activation**. Then, discard this card.

The card doesn't care about any special rules about its target in a specific scenario. It just does as written unless explicitly prevented elsewhere by mission rules or by the **cannot** keyword, which is an exception to the `Golden Rules`. *(Page 2, Rules Reference Guide)*

Phrasing which contains a finale spoiler:

> Instead of activating **as normal**, Darth Vader performs 1 action after each hero's activation. *(Page 41, Campaign Guide)*

Even though the mission rules prevent the gain of activations every round **as normal**, it does not prevent *other* gains of activations.  It instead reads as a replacement effect for the core rules which govern figures gaining activations during the Activation Phase. *(Page 3, Rules Reference Guide)*

Therefore, the card can grant one activation.

`Activation` is defined as:

> During a figure's activation, it performs up to **two actions**. *(Page 3, Rules Reference Guide)*

Thus, the group performs up to two actions.

`Group` is defined as:

> All figures that correspond to a single Deployment card or Hero sheet are a group. *(Page 13, Rules Reference Guide)*

So this works on both regular deployment groups and villains.